# dynamically load contents on IOS 5 application

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am new to IOS development and I need to load contents (buttons) dynamically when the application first starts. Can anyone help me guide towards that? I attended training but unfortunately I didn't learn that. I already have a method in ViewController but how could I execute that method onload?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You can use ViewDidLoad - it's a delegate method that gets automatically called when the ViewController's View Loads and you can do your custom loading there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a tutorial you might find useful:
http://blog.austinlouden.com/post/47644627216/your-first-ios-app-100-programmatically

It's a 2 part tutorial showing how to add content programmatically.

Here's an example:

```
// create a button object
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];    

// attach a method 'buttonPressed' when the button is pressed.
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchDown]; 

// set the text shown on the button
[button setTitle:@"buttonTitle" forState:UIControlStateNormal]; 

// set the size of the button
button.frame = CGRectMake(80.0, 210.0, 160.0, 40.0); 

// add the button to your view
[view addSubview:button];
```

Comment: This is perfect. It gives me some direction. Thank You!